# How can I keep the Double Bass's endpin from sliding on the floor?

Tags: double-bass

A really big problem I have when performing with my double bass, is that the endpin keeps sliding on the floor. Unless there is a carpet or the floor is grainy (or something that isn't slippery), I have to keep the bass from sliding. This is really tiresome, because I have to actually hold the bass, not just balance it against my body. At home I have a carpet on the floor, so this doesn't happen.

Is there something double bassists use on the live shows to prevent the bass from sliding?

Comment: Tried the rubber 'ferrule' that is found on the bottom of walking sticks?  Or a door stop that would normally get screwed into the floor, both softish rubber?

Comment: This & many like it... https://www.caswells-strings.co.uk/product/double-bass-endpin-ferrule/ or this beast - http://www.superspikes.co.uk/bassspike.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling **Bass endpin ferrule**
brought some simple

[image]
https://www.caswells-strings.co.uk/product/double-bass-endpin-ferrule/

and some not-so-simple

[image][image]
http://www.superspikes.co.uk/bassspike.html

answers to the slippage problem.

<sup>UK bias because that's my home country.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Also you can search for a "rock stop" which is a larger puck of non-slip rubber with a metal cup in the middle that your end pin sits down in.  Probably goes by multiple names, but my son (who plays cello) has a couple in his case that he uses quite successfully to keep his cello in place while playing.  I'm sure the same would work fine for a double bass.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called an [Endpin Anchor](http://www.google.com/search?q=upright%20bass%20endpin%20anchor) or an [Endpin Stop](http://www.google.com/search?q=upright%20bass%20endpin%20stop).  There are many types, from simple rubber ferrules to cups that attach to straps that can be tied off to a chair or whatever else.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen cello players tether their endpin to the chair they sit in with a short, looped rope. Since you stand, maybe you can put a foot on the other end. Just an idea.

Answer (score -3):

A simple beanbag will also work acceptably